# How can I manually mark an input in my mdbootstrap angular.js form as invalid?

Tags: angular, typescript, mdbootstrap

With my current code I am able to make inputs show up as invalid if they are blank or do not fit the format of the input's type (eg: email must have the '@' and '.' format).

My next step is to make sure the password and confirmPassword fields match up. I have created a function that compares the two, but am having a lot of trouble implementing it with the mdbootstrap form.

The function that I have been playing around with:

```
mustMatch(controlName: string, matchingControlName: string) {
return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
  const control = formGroup.controls[controlName];
  const matchingControl = formGroup.controls[matchingControlName];

  if (matchingControl.errors && !matchingControl.errors.mustMatch) {
    // var passwordInput = document.getElementById('password');
    // passwordInput.classList.remove('ng-valid');
    // passwordInput.classList.add('ng-invalid');
    formGroup.controls['password'].setErrors({'incorrect': true});
    return;
  }

  if (control.value !== matchingControl.value) {
    matchingControl.setErrors({ mustMatch: true });
  } else {
    matchingControl.setErrors(null);
  }
};
```

}

The elements I need to make invalid:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-outline">
        <input formControlName="password" type="password" id="password" class="form-control pb-3" required/>
        <label class="form-label" for="password">Password</label>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter your password.</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div class="form-outline">
        <input formControlName="confirmPassword" type="password" id="confirmPass" class="form-control pb-3" required/>
        <label class="form-label" for="confirmPass">Confirm Password</label>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please confirm your password.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The initialization of the form:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
document.querySelectorAll('.form-outline').forEach((formOutline) => {
  new mdb.Input(formOutline).init();
});
this.setupSignupForm();

const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation');

Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach((form) => {
  form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    if (!form.checkValidity()) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
    form.classList.add('was-validated');
  }, false);
});



setupSignupForm(): void {
    this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: ['', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.email,
        ]],
      confirmEmail: ['',
        [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.email,
        ]],
      joinCode: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      confirmPassword: ['',
        [
          Validators.required,
        ]]
    }, {
      validators: [this.mustMatch('password', 'confirmPassword'), this.mustMatch('email', 'confirmEmail')]
    });
  }
```

Please let me know if you can figure out how to do this. I have been bashing my head against the wall for a while on this problem!

[Here is a picture of what I am dealing with:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMUqA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's better to use the `validator` for each `form-control` you need instead of the whole `form-group`, because:

- The `form-group` validators will be checked on any changes within the form, even if the changes are not related to the target `form-control`(s) (`password` and `email` in your case).
- You have to handle setting the errors (`setErrors`) manually, and the same form removing them.

Instead of that you can achieve it by assigning the validator to the `form-control` itself, like the following:

```js
setupSignupForm(): void {
  this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: ['', Validators.required],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    confirmEmail: [
      '',
      [Validators.required, Validators.email, this.mustMatch('email')]
    ],
    joinCode: ['', Validators.required],
    password: ['', Validators.required],
    confirmPassword: ['', [Validators.required, this.mustMatch('password')]]
  });
}

mustMatch(matchingControlName: string): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if (!control.parent) return;

    const matchingCtrlValue = control.parent.get(matchingControlName).value;

    if (control.value !== matchingCtrlValue) {
      return { mustMatch: true };
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: There is an issue with this solution. Let's say email="tes@test.com" and confirmEmail="test@test.com". The confirmEmail will not be valid since the two fields do not match. 

If you now change the email field to be equal to "test@test.com" without editing the confirmEmail field, the confirmEmail field still won't be valid, because the mustMatch() function won't be called until confirmEmail is edited.

Answer (score 0):

mdboostrat validations works adding :invalid and :valid styles to parent .was-validated class. But you can also add a class is-valid or is-invalid to yours inputs (and not add was-validated to the form)

So I suggest another approach:

1.-remove in your code

```
/**Remove this lines**
const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation');

Array.prototype.slice.call(forms).forEach((form) => {
  form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    ...
});
```

2.-Use in yours input some like

```
<input [ngClass]="'is-valid':form.get('password').invalid && 
                   form.get('password').touched;
                  'is-invalid':form.get('password').valid && 
                   form.get('password').touched">
```

Well repeat in all ours input the ngClass is a bit "bizarro". So Why not use a Directive that make it for us?

Imagine a directive like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '.form-control'
})
export class MdClassDirective {
  @HostBinding('class.is-valid') get valid() {
    return (
      (!this.form || this.form.classList.contains('submitted')) &&
      this.control &&
      this.control.touched &&
      this.control.valid
    );
  }
  @HostBinding('class.is-invalid') get invalid() {
    return (
      (!this.form || this.form.classList.contains('submitted')) &&
      this.control &&
      this.control.touched &&
      this.control.invalid
    );
  }
  form: any;
  constructor(@Optional() private control: NgControl, el: ElementRef) {

    //we need get the "html form"
    this.form = el.nativeElement;

    while (this.form.parentElement && !(this.form instanceof HTMLFormElement)) {
      this.form = this.form.parentElement;
    }
  }
}
```

This directive add the class is-valid or is-invalid to your input with class "form-control" if is touched and the "form" has as class submitted. So this work in an html form like, e.g. -see the [class.submitted]="submitted"-

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submitted=true;submit()" 
      [class.submitted]="submitted">
  <input class="form-control" formControlName="name" >
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Don't forget in function submited mark the elements as inputs

```
  submit() {
    this.form.markAllAsTouched();
  }
```

In this way you can use a customValidator in Angular normally.